# sub function in r does not replace the first match

Tags: r, string

I am trying to manipulate a character vector and want to delete all characters before the first occurrence of a specific string using `sub` function in r, since the function performs replacement of the first match, but in my code `sub` replaces the last but not the first match?

Here below is an example

```
  Vec <-  c("ID1.P.001", "ID2.P.002") # character vector 
  # I want to get rid of all characters before the first dot (including the dot)
  # So i want to get this vector 
  c("P.001", "P.002")
  #[1] "P.001" "P.002"
  # my code  
  sub('.*\\.', "", Vec )
  #[1] "001" "002"
  # sub replace the last not the first match !!
```

How can i use `sub` to get rid of characters before the first match (including the pattern)?

Comment: Try `sub("^[^.]+\\.", "", Vec)

Comment: `sub(".*(P\\.\\d+)", "\\1", Vec)`

Comment: The issue is not that it removed the last match, it's that regular expressions are typically *greedy* by default. In this case, it found a literal dot `.` and removed everything before it. Regexes are quite powerful, but without strict controls they can be liabilities in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the `*` quantifier lazy (opposed to the default greedy matching) by adding a `?` after it. I.e.:

```
sub('.*?\\.', "", Vec)
[1] "P.001" "P.002"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can specify the start (`^`) of the string, match the characters that are not a `.` (`[^.]+` - one or more characters that are not a dot) followed by a dot (`\\.` - metacharacter - so escaping, within the `[]`, it would be evaluated as . though) and in replacement, specify as blank (`""`)

```
sub("^[^.]+\\.", "", Vec) 
#[1] "P.001" "P.002"
```